# In Android Studio I get a Run Edit Configuration dialog box

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm trying to run an Android App in Android Studio. When I click the Run or Debug menu options I get the attached dialog box. 
[image]

Can you explain why I am getting it and how to resolve it?

Only the green button is clickable. When I click on it I get the following:
[image]

I used to be able to click Run or Debug and the app would launch. I'm not sure what is expected at this point to get app to run.

Thanks

Comment: It probably means that `Android Studio` didnt find any default `Launcher` activity defined in the `AndroidMenifest`.

Comment: Normally this dialog appeared when default activity means launcher activity no defined in manifest.
So click on this popup ->Android application->Launch Option and choose Default Activity.

If Android application not display in list then check Manifest file

Comment: Thanks I will check.

Comment: because android studio is not able to detect the gradle settings